# Elasticsearch Index type doesn't changed after updating status

Tags: elasticsearch, indexing, lucene, elasticsearch-plugin, sense

I've made some _bulk insert successfully , now I'm trying to make query with date range and filter something like:

```
{
   "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must": [{
                "terms": {
                    "mt_id": [613]
                }
            },
            {
                "range": {
                    "time": {
                        "gt": 1470009600000,
                        "lt": 1470009600000
                    }
                }
            }]
        }
    }
```

Unfortunately I got no results , Now I noticed that the index mapping is created after bulk insert as following:

```
{
  "agg__ex_2016_8_3": {
    "mappings": {
      "player": {
        "properties": {
          "adLoad": {
            "type": "long"
          },
         "mt_id": {
           "type": "long"
          },
          "time": {
            "type": "string"
          }
        }
      },
```

As a solution I tried to change the index mapping with:

```
PUT /agg__ex_2016_8_3/_mapping/player
{
  "properties" : {
    "mt_id" : {
      "type" :    "long",
      "index":    "not_analyzed"
    }
  }
}
```

got

```
{
  "acknowledged": true
}
```

and PUT /agg__ex_2016_8_3/_mapping/player

```
{
  "properties" : {
    "time" : {
      "type" :    "date",
     "format" : "yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss"
    }
  }
}
```

got:

```
{
   "error": {
      "root_cause": [
         {
            "type": "remote_transport_exception",
            "reason": "[vj_es_c1-esc13][10.132.69.145:9300][indices:admin/mapping/put]"
         }
      ],
      "type": "illegal_argument_exception",
      "reason": "mapper [time] of different type, current_type [string], merged_type [date]"
   },
   "status": 400
}
```

but nothing happened , and still doesn't get any results.

What i'm doing wrong ? ( I must work with http , not using curl)

Thanks!!

Comment: The `time` field being of type string is not so good. Can you show a sample document which you think should match?

Comment: Val:   , I've Edited question the document :  
      {
        "_index": "agg__ex_2016_8_2",
        "_type": "player",
        "_id": "104",
        "_score": 4.244597,
        "_source": {
          "time": "1470009600000",
          "domain": "organisemyhouse.com",
          "master_domain": "613###organisemyhouse.com",
          "playerRequets": 4,
          "playerLoads": 0
          "c_Id": 0,
          "cb_Id": 0,
          "mt_Id": 613
        }
      },

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
# 1. delete index
DELETE agg__ex_2016_8_3

# 2. recreate it with the proper mapping
PUT agg__ex_2016_8_3
{
  "mappings": {
    "player": {
      "properties": {
        "adLoad": {
          "type": "long"
        },
        "mt_id": {
          "type": "long"
        },
        "time": {
          "type": "date"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

# 3. create doc
PUT agg__ex_2016_8_3/player/104
{
  "time": "1470009600000",
  "domain": "organisemyhouse.com",
  "master_domain": "613###organisemyhouse.com",
  "playerRequets": 4,
  "playerLoads": 0,
  "c_Id": 0,
  "cb_Id": 0,
  "mt_Id": 613
}

# 4. search
POST agg__ex_2016_8_3/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "terms": {
            "mt_Id": [
              613
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "range": {
            "time": {
              "gte": 1470009600000,
              "lte": 1470009600000
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: My Problem that i used Bulk insert with the following structure: {index : { _index : agg_8_3_2016 , type : player, _id : i++ } }; , it create as a default date "String".....etc , is it any way to create at first with "bulk Insert" different type of Date , or other field with long ???   Thankssss :) , I can't recreate all the time the index, its production ....

Comment: You can do steps 1 and 2 first, then you can run your bulk and it will parse the string timestamps properly as dates.

Comment: After step 2: GOT  {
   "error": {
      "root_cause": [
         {
            "type": "mapper_parsing_exception",
            "reason": "Root mapping definition has unsupported parameters:  [mappings : {player={ mt_Id={type=long}, playerLoads={type=long}, playerRequets={type=long}, time={type=date}}}}]"
         }
      ],
      "type": "mapper_parsing_exception",
      "reason": "Root mapping definition has unsupported parameters:  [mappings : {player=cb_Id={type=long}, child_domain= time={type=date}}}}]"
   },
   "status": 400
}

Comment: Please update your question with the exact steps you're taking, it's not clear what went wrong in your case and the state of your index.

Comment: Great ,  Its works Thanks a lot !  The date query is something like :  "range": {
                    "time": {
                        "gt": "2016-08-01||/d",
                       "lt": "2016-09-01||/d",
                       "format": "yyyy-MM-dd"
                    }
                }  , is it no way to query with "timestamp" ?     , the 2nd , Can I create bulk with "Date" type ? ( without creating pre-mapping)  ???

Comment: If you check my answer, the query uses the timestamp directly, no need to format. You can send your bulk without creating the mapping first **if and only if** your date field is properly formatted with a recognized date such as `2016-08-01T00:00:00.000Z`

Comment: Ok ,thanks the query works !! As i understand i should make bulk insert into documents date with format "2016-08-01T00:00:00.000Z" instead of long timestamp ?